# How to change app's name in firebase google's sign in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

I have an old project on firebase which name was randomly generated and it became resplendent-inferno-X.

When users are about to sign in the application using Google sign-in it shows something like:

> choose the account to enter in the
>   resplendent-inferno-x.firebaseapp.com.

Is possible to change this name in the google sign-in popup? How?

I didn't find how to change in the firebase console

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be changed by updating "Public-facing name" on the [settings page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/).

Answer (score 3):

You can change it using Firebase Hosting custom domains. Check the instructions in the official docs on [Customizing the redirect domain for Google sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#customizing-the-redirect-domain-for-google-sign-in).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app's branding information to be displayed, the app needs to be verified. See the circumstances under which app verification is needed [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#circumstances).